# PySpark :- How to pass encoding format to sc.newAPIHadoopFile config

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I need to read an ISO-8859-1 encoded file, do some operations and create parquet file.
Reading file using sc.newAPIHadoopFile() and creating pyspark DF, but not able to find out config property to send encoding format to sc.newAPIHadoopFile().

I know we can send the encoding format to df by using encoding option

```
        df = spark.read.format(
        "com.databricks.spark.csv").schema(schema).option(
        "escape", '\"').option(
        "quote", '\"').option(
        "header", "false").option(
        "encoding", "ISO-8859-1").csv(rdd)
```

but still Is there a way to send encoding format directly to sc.newAPIHadoopFile()

Comment: why are you using `newAPIHadoopFile` instead of reading CSV directly? What is the Spark version?

Comment: We have a custom row delimiters configured which can not be provided while reading csv file hence we are using newAPIHadoopFile. We are using spark 2.4.5